# SparkNLP NerDLModel load throws NoSuchMethodException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, named-entity-recognition, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I am currently using John Snow labs SparkNLP library to train a custom NER Model. I am able to successfully complete the training and the model is getting saved to the disk. When I try to load the model for next step to actually tag some sample data I run into the following error. I using the Ubuntu on Windows 10. spark-nlp_2.12:3.1.2 with Spark 3.1.2, scala 2.12.10 OpenJDK 8

I have also tried the same on PySpark I get same  the exact error
pyspark error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
> org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel.(java.lang.String)
> at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
> at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
> at org.apache.spark.ml.util.DefaultParamsReader.load(ReadWrite.scala:468)
> at com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.FeaturesReader.load(ParamsAndFeaturesReadable.scala:12)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
> at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
> at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
> at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
> at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Any help is appreciated. Scala version error
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:

> org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel.(java.lang.String)   at
> java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)   at
> java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)   at
> org.apache.spark.ml.util.DefaultParamsReader.load(ReadWrite.scala:468)
> at
> com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.FeaturesReader.load(ParamsAndFeaturesReadable.scala:12)
> at
> com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.FeaturesReader.load(ParamsAndFeaturesReadable.scala:8)

```
val loaded_ner_model = NerDLModel.load("./NER_bert_prod_20200221")
   .setInputCols("sentence", "token", "bert")
   .setOutputCol("ner")
```

Comment: Can we see the code for how you saved the model file?